# Splicing SQL display Chinese characters problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following SQL script which I hope to cross apply to select Chinese column name

```
CREATE TABLE #temp([color] varchar(5), [size] varchar(5),[AQty] varchar(10),[BQty] varchar(10),[CQty] varchar(10),[DQty] varchar(10));
    
    INSERT INTO #temp([color], [size], [AQty], [BQty],[CQty],[DQty])
    VALUES   ('A1', 'L','1','2','3','4')
           , ('A1', 'M','1','2','3','4')
           , ('A1', 'S','1','2','3','4')
           , ('A1', 'XL','1','2','3','4')
           , ('B1', 'L','1','2','3','4')
           , ('B1', 'M','1','2','3','4')
           , ('B1', 'S','1','2','3','4')
           , ('B1', 'XL','1','2','3','4')
           , ('B1', 'XXL','1','2','3','4')
           , ('C1', 'L','1','2','3','4')
           , ('C1', 'S','1','2','3','4')
    
    declare @cols as varchar(max), @sql varchar(max)
    select @cols = STRING_AGG(col, ', ') from (
        select distinct QUOTENAME(size) as col from #temp
    ) as t
    
    set @sql = '
    select color, col as total, ' + @cols + '
    from(
        select color, size, col, [value]
        from #temp
        cross apply (
        select ''总数一'', cast(AQty as varchar(10)) union all
        select ''总数二'', cast(BQty as varchar(10)) union all
        select ''总数三'', cast(CQty as varchar(10)) union all
        select ''总数四'', cast(DQty as varchar(10)) 
        ) c(col, [value])
    ) d
    pivot
    (
      max(value)
      for size in (' + @cols + ')
    ) piv
    order by color, total
    '
    exec(@sql)
```

But now exec SQL is display garbled when I hope to display Chinese column name

```
color   total   L   M   S   XL  XXL
A1       ???    4   4   4   4   NULL
B1       ???    4   4   4   4   4
C1       ???    4   NULL4   NULLNULL
```

I tried to change it like this, change variable `nvarchar`, set `@sql` with `N` and change cross apply select with `N`, but now not work.

```
        declare @cols as nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)
        set @sql = N'
        select color, col as total, ' + @cols + '
        from(
            select color, size, col, [value]
            from #temp
            cross apply (
            select N''总数一'', cast(AQty as varchar(10)) union all
            select N''总数二'', cast(BQty as varchar(10)) union all
            select N''总数三'', cast(CQty as varchar(10)) union all
            select N''总数四'', cast(DQty as varchar(10)) 
            ) c(col, [value])
        ) d
        pivot
        (
          max(value)
          for size in (' + @cols + ')
        ) piv
        order by color, total
        '
        exec(@sql)
```

Comment: You need to have the language pack installed in Control Panel

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding `N` after `+ @cols +`

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'
select color, col as total, ' + @cols + N'
from(
    select color, size, col, [value]
    from #temp
    cross apply (
    select N''总数一'', cast(AQty as varchar(10)) union all
    select N''总数二'', cast(BQty as varchar(10)) union all
    select N''总数三'', cast(CQty as varchar(10)) union all
    select N''总数四'', cast(DQty as varchar(10)) 
    ) c(col, [value])
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for size in (' + @cols + ')
) piv
order by color, total
'
exec(@sql)
```